# Why does illustrator invert my images when i export as CMYK?

Tags: color, cmyk

[image]I have this problem on Ai-cc, whenever I export-export as.. eventhough my document is in CMYK and on the final step I export as CMYK my image's result is that the colours are inverted. I have to export as RGB so i can get a normal looking image. I dont know why this happens, as on my other pc in Ai CS6 I dont have this problem. I dont know if its a color profile the problem or smth, Im not an expert on Ai, I just do the designs :p I haven't change any settings also.
When I open the image in Ps though, it looks normal!

Maybe its a windows photo-viewer problem?!

Can anyone pleaseee help?

Comment: Why are you *exporting* CMYK images? Typically *saving* CMYK files is better. Export is *designed* for web/app images that need to be RGB.

Comment: I export so I can have jpgs of the artworks im doing. If I have a file with logos in it for example, how im I going to show them to other people? I dont want to save as pdf. jpg is easy and more practical. is there another way to get jpgs from Ai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **exporting** images for review via email/web links, using **RGB** for the color space is generally preferred.

While there *can* be a color shift, typically going *from* CMYK *to* RGB isn't a problem. The RGB gamut includes all the CMYK colors, so you aren't inherently altering the gamut of available colors (unlike going *from* RGB *to* CMYK).

90% of clients won't know or understand CMYK v RGB anyway. And trying to explain it can be futile at times (because they don't really care, and there's no reason for them to care). Send them RGB images.

CMYK jpgs can *always* cause issues with some viewing applications because the viewing app may not understand that a jpg *can be* CMYK. So, they see the .jpg marker and treat all jpgs as RGB images. There's no such animal as a CMYK PNG or GIF.

If CMYK image files *are desired*, then **Save As** is always a better and more preferable method. But, image formats will be restricted due to which formats actually support CMYK. I find PDF is sufficient for CMYK images.

Comment: Thank you Scott for ur time! Ur right about customers etc, but its kind of annoying every time I have to save as.. to remember to change the top part to RGB always. The question is WHY they are previewed like that, when on my work's pc, on Ai cs6 with the SAME photo viewer this doesn't happen.
So there's nothing I can do about it?

Comment: How can I send you an image here so you can see how they look on my pc?

Comment: Generally Windows Explorer or the Mac Finder aren't concerned about CMYK images. They may or may not display correctly - or at least it's accuracy. CMYK is really not used by 90% of users. As for AICS6 v AICC.. Adobe may have changed things under the hood, no telling. Truth is. . I rarely use "export". I either Save as, or Save for Web.

Comment: Hmm.. I see... So how DO I save as in Ai if I dont export?

Comment: File > Save As -- If you need a JPG/PNG.. File > Save for Web

Comment: You mean export>save for web. Because in save as there isnt such option. Thats why I use export. Cz I cant find another way to get a jpg. :/

Comment: Yeah sorry, they moved it.. Export > Save for Web (legacy) -- Option 3 is to merely open the AI file with Photoshop and save a from JPG there.